# How to get to documenCompleted event from IWebBrowser2?

Tags: winapi, activex

I am working on implementing oauth in a Win32 app. I can host the web browser control in my app and, using IWebBrowser2 interface, am able to navigate to the specified oauth link.

When login succeeds, the server sends the response as a json document that contains the authorization token that I need.

I have seen C#/WPF examples where the client code captures the token in WebBrower.DocumentCompleted event.

I am wondering how I can reach to document-completed event in my C++ application. All I have is IWebBrowser2 object at the moment. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) WebBrowser2.QueryInterface(IConnectionPointContainer, ConnectionPointContainer)

2) ConnectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(DIID_DWebBrowserEvents2, ConnectionPoint)

3) ConnectionPoint.Advise(Self, ConnectionPointCookie)

4) Self must implement IDispatch

5) Inside Self.Invoke you will catch all events include DISPID_DOCUMENTCOMPLETE.

6) Don`t forget to call ConnectionPoint.Unadvise at the end of your work.

Comment: Awesome. Very precise and exactly what I needed. Regards.